# Alexa skill with python api request

Tags: python-2.7, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

My alexa skill is supposed to take the input from the user then lookup the route_code to input it into the api request url.  In local testing it works but now for some reason my code when testing with alexa it does not input the route_code I am not sure what might be missing or where it's messing up because it does have a successful match when i look at the JSON.  It currently just outputs the repromt_text and not the message it should from the api request

Below is where it does not seem to be working as expected.  The full code is here https://github.com/meyrickj/Alexa-skill-Philly-Tranist/blob/master/lambda_function.py

```
def get_status(intent):
session_attributes = {}
card_title = "Septa Status"
speech_output = "I'm not sure which route you wanted the status for. " \
                "Please try again. Try asking about the Market Frankford line or a bus route, such as Route 66."
reprompt_text = "I'm not sure which route you wanted the status for. " \
                "Try asking about the Market Frankford line or a bus route, such as Route 66."
should_end_session = False

if "Route" in intent["slots"]:
    route_name = intent["slots"]["Route"]["value"]

    route_code = get_route_code(route_name.lower())

    if (route_code != "unkn"):

        response = urllib2.urlopen(API_BASE_URL + "/Alerts/get_alert_data.php?req1=" + route_code)
        route_status = json.load(response)  

        if len(route_status[0]["current_message"]) > 0:
            speech_output = "The current status of" + route_status[0]["route_name"] + route_status[0]["current_message"] 
        else:
            speech_output = "The " + route_status[0]["route_name"] + " is running normally."   

        reprompt_text = ""

return build_response(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
   card_title, speech_output, reprompt_text, should_end_session))
```

Comment: What "JSON" are you referring to in your question? The one from Alexa that invokes your skill? How do you know the intent contains the `Route` slot? When you say it just outputs the reprompt, that would mean the `if "Route" in intent["slots"]` is `False`, hence the whole branch never evaluates.

Comment: When I check the input json it finds the match in my route slot so it should pass that value to the python code right?  "slots": {
    "route": {
     "name": "route",
     "value": "route 66",
     "resolutions": {
      "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
       {
        "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.xxxlist_of_routes",
        "status": {
         "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
        },
        "values": [
         {
          "value": {
           "name": "route 66",

Comment: The slot is named `route`, not `Route`, that's why you don't have a match. Change the code to `if 'route' in intent["slots"]`. Similarly in the next line where you get its value.